# Time between specific Daenerys events in A Dance With Dragons

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Is there a canon timeline for *A Dance With Dragons*?

I'm specifically interested in how much time passes between when Daenerys rides off on [Drogon](http://wiki.westeros.org/index.php/Drogon) after that disastrous day in Daznak's Pit and when we get her last chapter in *A Dance With Dragons*.

She mentions that her hair had been burned off again, but that it was 'finally growing back' which makes it seem like months but I didn't get a clear sense of time from events happening in Meereen while she is gone.

Comment: There isn't much need for spoiler tags if you've mentioned the source in the title

Comment: I don't like your edits, but I'll leave them because I can't figure out how to get it back the way I had it. And I disagree with your comment about not needing the spoiler tag.

Comment: You can always roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @Zoe I guess what Richard means is that someone reading the title of your question would not be served by its entire content being covered by spoiler tag, as then they might as well not read the question at all. Which they would not do, if they read the title and did not want to be spoiled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not exactly canon, but [this is an impressive fan-created spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj_uNZmcJaTddG9BVU5tRnJJTE5KcE5JRkFha1ZfNUE#gid=8) that attempts to put a timeline to the books. The column to the very right describes the reasoning behind each event's time stamp. According to it, around 4 weeks have passed between the events at Daznak's Pit and Dany's final chapter in ADWD. The reasoning being:

> "Many days have passed at chapter's opening. Three days pass during
>   chapter. ""...she picked at a broken blister. Her skin was pink and 
>   tender, and a pale milky fluid was leaking from her cracked palms, but
>   her burns were healing."" Second degree burns would take around four
>   weeks to heal. NOTE: There's not enough information to firmly
>   establish when Dany's last chapter occurs in relation to the Meereen
>   action. We put down a guesstimate but we won't really know until the
>   next book."

Comment: Hair grows about 1cm per month (4 weeks), which sounds like a reasonable guesstimate for "finally growing back".